Unable to set balance in Hardhat
I am trying to set balance to an account provided by hardhat but I'm unable to do so. I'm using Infura provider to fork mainnet.
Here is my code:
import { ethers, JsonRpcProvider, formatUnits, parseEther } from 'ethers';
import { Token } from '@uniswap/sdk-core';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { setBalance } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";

dotenv.config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(process.env.INFURA_URL);
const WETH = new Token(1, '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2', 18, 'WETH', 'Wrapped Ether');
const DAI = new Token(1, '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F', 18, 'DAI', 'Dai Stablecoin');

const walletAddress = process.env.WALLET_ADDRESS as string;

async function getTokenBalance(tokenAddress: string, walletAddress: string): Promise<string> {
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, [
        'function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)',
        'function decimals() view returns (uint8)',
    ], provider);

    const balance = await tokenContract.balanceOf(walletAddress);
    const decimals = await tokenContract.decimals();
    return formatUnits(balance, decimals);
}

async function getEthBalance(walletAddress: string): Promise<string> {
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(walletAddress);
    return formatUnits(balance, 18);
}

async function main() {
    try {
        const balance = parseEther("100");
        await setBalance(walletAddress, balance);
        const ethBalance = await getEthBalance(walletAddress);
        const wethBalance = await getTokenBalance(WETH.address, walletAddress);
        const daiBalance = await getTokenBalance(DAI.address, walletAddress);

        console.log(`ETH Balance: ${ethBalance}`);
        console.log(`WETH Balance: ${wethBalance}`);
        console.log(`DAI Balance: ${daiBalance}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching balances:', error);
    }
}

main();


and here is my hardhat config:
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "hardhat-deal";

let config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.27",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<my project id>",
      },
      accounts: {
        count: 50,
        accountsBalance: "9000000000000000000000000",
      },
    },
  },
};

export default config;


Even while trying to set balance in config file, starting the hardhat node does show the mentioned balance, but while getting the balance from the code there is little to no ethereum in the account. I'm also unable to set the balance in the account from code.
